# How to upload user defined function to Google cloud MySQL instance

Tags: mysql, plugins, user-defined-functions, google-cloud-sql

I am running a MySQL database instance on Google Cloud, and I am currently trying to upload a shared library file (`my_library.so`) to my plugin directory, so that I can declare it as an user-defined function to call in MySQL queries.

Does someone know how to do it?

It seems that the Google cloud console does not give me access to the files in my instance. Also, I have not been able to upload it using MySQL workbench.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Cloud SQL does not support uploading compiled code.

Comment: Does this mean that there is no way of implementing UDF on a google-cloud-sql instance?

Comment: Not using native code, no. Stored Procedures are fully supported: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html